# how to print xvals and dNdX(xvals) like (x,y)

Tags: python

I want to know how to print xvals and dNdX(xvals) like (x,y)
becuz I want to pick specific point for make chi-square fit

i tried to use

```
import numpy as np

z0 = 2

fnames = 'gammas.dat'

data = np.genfromtxt(fnames, names=True, dtype=None)

z = data["N03"]

index = np.where(np.abs(z-z0) <1)

xvals = data["N01"][index]

yvals = data["No2"][index]/xvals

loadspec = interp1d(xvals, yvals)

def dNdx(x):

    y = loadspec(x)

    if (y<0):

        return 0

    else:

        return y**2*z0

plt.plot(xvals, [dNdx(x) for x in xvals])

print(xvals, dNdx(xvals))

plt.show()
```

this is my xvals

```
 [1.12201845e-09 1.25892541e-09 1.41253754e-09 1.58489319e-09
 1.77827941e-09 1.99526231e-09 2.23872114e-09 2.51188643e-09
 2.81838293e-09 3.16227766e-09 3.54813389e-09 3.98107171e-09
....]
```

this is my dNdx(x) I print it with print([dNdx(x) for x in xvals])

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.063782730723477e-08, 9.48097356727775e-09, 8.449926586257558e-09, 7.531004997163314e-09, ...]
```

I want the output form print(xvals[1]), print(dNdx[1]) be 1.12e-09  0.0

Comment: Hi Tanech, please edit your question and try to clarify it by adding some information (ideally by adding a few lines to the code): `np` must be numpy (`import numpy as np`), but what is`dNdx`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're just trying to pair the values in the two lists, then you can use the `zip()` function and print the result?

Comment: Thanks for answer,  when I do the code, I just want to fit data for `(xvals,dNdx(xvals))` and `dNdX` is `z0*y**2`. Now I want to make output be like `(xvals,dNdX)` for making chi-square fit. but the problem is I dont know how to pick pair of `(xvals,dNdx)` I try to print to see the data first but got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you are looking for ?

```
values = {0:"1.12e-09" , 1: "0.0"}
print(values[0], values[1])
```

Basically, you can pass multiple values to `print` and it will print those values. If this is not what you were looking for , can you please clarify ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this quite easily:

```
for entry in xvals:
    calculated_value = dNdx(entry)
    print(f"{entry} {calculated_value}")
```